# Problem with "equality" in std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I see some behaviour in `std::unordered_set` that I need to understand  better.

I created a `struct` that also provides a "hash" function and an "equality" function. The struct contains values for an interval, the lower and upper bound. I use the struct in the `std::unordered_set` definition also as the "hash" and "equal_to" template argument. Many will not like it, but for the MRE it is OK. No need to write separate functors.

I want to add only disjoint intervals to a `std::unordered_set`. So, I use a selfmade `disjoint`-function and consider 2 intervals to be equal, if they overlap.

I have written some test function (MRE) below.

Why can I insert intervals [1,5] and [2,3] although they overlap and are considered to be equal?

Maybe becuase of the different hash values and the nature of the underlying hash table in the `std::unordered_set`? Please kindly confirm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Interval {
    int left{};
    int right{};
    bool isDisjoint(const Interval& other) const {
        return left < other.right && right < other.left;
    }
    // Hash function
    std::size_t operator()(const Interval& i) const {
        std::size_t result = static_cast<std::size_t>(i.left) + (static_cast<std::size_t>(i.right) << 16);
        return result;
    }
    // Comparison for equality
    bool operator ()(const Interval& lhs, const Interval& rhs) const  {
        bool result =  not lhs.isDisjoint(rhs);
        return  result;
    }
    //bool operator== (const Interval& other) const {
    //    bool result = not isDisjoint(other);
    //    return  result;
    //}

    // Simple output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Interval& i) {
        return os << '[' << i.left << ','<< i.right << ']';
    }
};

std::vector<Interval> intervals{ {1,5},{2,3},{1,10},{5,10},{6,8} };

int main() {

    std::unordered_set< Interval, Interval, Interval> disjointIntervals{};

    // Special test for first 2 intervals
    std::cout << ((not intervals[0].isDisjoint(intervals[1]))?"[1,5] is equal to [2,3]": "[1,5] is NOT equal to [2,3]") << '\n';

    for (const auto& i : intervals) {
        // Test for hash values. They are all different
        std::cout << "Interval: " << (static_cast<std::size_t>(i.left) + (static_cast<std::size_t>(i.right) << 16)) << " \tHash: " << (i.left + (i.right << 16)) << '\n';
        disjointIntervals.insert(i);
    }
    for (const auto& i : disjointIntervals)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Are entries with different hashes ever checked for equality? I don't think so. I believe your comparison is never run, because the hashes are different. Maybe not the best datastructure to check for overlapping intervals.

Comment: I would add `or (left > other.right)` to the `isDisjoint` method.

Comment: The equality predicate is only used if two elements have the same hash. Its purpose is to determine whether a key/value should be inserted or an existing entry should be updated. (Since two unequal keys can have the same hash, you need a way to distinguish between them.)

Comment: This `std::unordered_set< Interval, Interval, Interval>` is so weird and clunky! `Interval` which is at the same time its own hash functor and equal functor!

Comment: @ArminMontigny Hash sets garantuee insertion and lookup with amortized constand time complexity. This would not be possible if you would compare a key with every existing key. That's the point of hashing :)

Comment: @ArminMontigny I don't think you can if there already are upvoted answers.

Comment: i don't think the question is stupid. Though a better quesiton would be what to do instead

Comment: As others have observed, hash tables fundamentally don’t work here. Instead, the data structure you’re looking for is the [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). There is no implementation in the C++ standard library but implementing a simple interval tree luckily isn’t hard.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unordered_set` is a hash set. Elements will be organized into buckets, where the hash of an element identifies the bucket it's in. (That's how you get amortized `O(1)` insertion and lookup).

By the nature of hashing, *different* objects can produce the *same* hash.
In this case and probably *only* in this case the comparison will be called to check wether two elements with equal hashes are indeed equal or not.

The two ranges `[1,5]` and `[2,3]` produce different hashes, thus will never be checked for equality.

---

It's not possible to produce identical hashes for overlapping ranges like you intend to. (unless the hash is *always* the same, which kind of defies the point of using a hash set).

I suggest to use different data structure. Maybe a sorted `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The named requirement [`Hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash) states:

> All evaluations of h(k) executed within a given execution of a program yield the same result for the same value of k.

Also for [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), the same in different words:

> For two parameters k1 and k2 that are equal, std::hash()(k1) == std::hash()(k2).

Roughly speaking, elements with the same hash end up in the same bucket, and because different elements may end up to have the same hash, only then they have to be checked for equality.

Your hash function does not produce the same hash for keys that are equal and thats wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the weird comments, I'm looking in the standard for the part where it says that the equality is not considered when two keys have the same hash.... But cannot clearly find it yet.